# Matlab: Applying threshold to one dimension in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix M(x,y). I want to apply a threshold in all values in x, such that if x

Example:

M = 1,   2;
   3,   4;
   5,   6;

If t = 5 is applied on the 1st dimension, the result will be

R = 0,   2;
   0,   4;
   5,   6;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way (use `M(:,1)` to select the first column; `M(:,1)<5` returns row indices for items in the first column that are lest than 5))-

```
> R = M;
> R(M(:,1)<5,1) = 0

R =

   0   2
   0   4
   5   6
```

Another -

```
R = M;
[i,j]=find(M(:,1)<5); % locate rows (i) and cols (j) where M(:,1) < 5
                      % so j is just going to be all 1
                      % and i has corresponding rows
R(i,1)=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it in a matrix of arbitrary dimensions:

```
thresh_min = 5;
M(M < thresh_min) = 0;
```

The statement `M < thresh_min` returns indices of M that are less than `thresh_min`.  Then, reindexing into `M` with these indices, you can set all of these valuse fitting your desired criterion to `0` (or whatever else).